# Trouble changing css with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to change the padding on my header so that it effectively is lowered onto the page. I have the following code which runs and does nothing:

```
function openPage() {
    var i, el = document.getElementById('headbar');
    for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
        el.style.paddingTop = el.style.paddingTop + 1;
    }
}
```

However, while trying to figure out why it wasn't working in the console I figured out that maybe it is because the padding must be written in pixels because the following works and changes the padding in the console:

```
document.getElementById('headbar').style.paddingTop='100px';
```

is there any way I could do this without Jquery and without having to make a substring and reconcatonating?

Comment: you can write you're own value normalization, but besides that you have to concat the string. all tough thats not the end of the world really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending `px` to the variable

```
 var fontSize = parseInt(el.style.paddingTop, 10);
 el.style.paddingTop = ( (!isNaN(fontSize) : fontSize : 0) + 1) + 'px';
```

Comment: This should work from what I understand but it does nothing in the end. hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple just do this:

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
     var px = (el.style.paddingTop + 1) + "px";
     el.style.paddingTop = px;
}
```

Comment: i see what you are doing here but el.style.paddingTop must return null because the padding is set to 1px